# Preventing windows 10 quick access from pinning folders under certain folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I would like to blacklist or permanently prevent windows explolrer from adding certain folders to the quick access folder. I have researched online and only found methods of removing already pinned items. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little C# app to achieve this.

https://github.com/jmaton/ClearRecentLinks

You can specify specific folders, filenames, and/or partial filenames.  Matching links will be deleted from Recent as well as from QuickAccess.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing so by adding what you want to quick access, and not recently used items.

1. Right click quick access.
2. Under privacy, uncheck the 2 squares.
3. Every item you want to show on quick access, right click on it and choose 'add to quick access'

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that doesn't quote resolve my issue.

Comment: Yea. Yt's a good work around. There isn't a blacklist for quick access.