# Is it possible to exclude a drive and all of it's content from showing up under quick access?

Tags: windows-10

I want to exclude a drive and all folders and files from that drive to show up under quick access.

The drive is an external hard drive, I only use once to twice a day. Because of this, the drive is on standby, most of the time. 
So every time I open the explorer it freezes for about 15 seconds to spin up the disk, unless I remove all files and folders from that drive from quick access manually.

This question is similar to this question: [Preventing windows 10 quick access from pinning folders under certain folder](https://superuser.com/questions/981730/preventing-windows-10-quick-access-from-pinning-folders-under-certain-folder)
But I think it's not a duplicate, because that question is about a folder and it's sub-folders, while my question is about a whole drive.

Also I don't want to completely disable recent files under quick access, because if they are quite useful from my internal drives.

Comment: The answer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/1018723/remove-network-drive-from-quick-access-panel?rq=1) question worked to remove my own external drive from quick access

Comment: @Thomas - I submitted that comment before the author made that clear.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable it by changing folder options.

1. Right click on Quick access and choose `Options`
2. Uncheck `Show frequently used folders in Quick access`
3. Click `OK`

All recent items will be gone.

If you want them back again enable the option.

Comment: As I wrote, I don't want to completely disable quick access. So this doesn't answer the question.